# How Can I hide part of my E-mail Address

Tags: php, mysql

Good Morning Guys! I need to get an e-mail from my database, but I'd like to show it like that:

`some*******@hotmail.com`

I'd like to show the beginning of my e-mail and then everything after @.

I'm using the following code:

```
$user_email= "********".substr($linha3['user_email'], -8);
```

It's working, but sometimes It doesn't appear in a nice way:

`********mail.com`

May you help me with any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RegEx to always match the e-mail username :

```php
echo preg_replace('/.*@/', '***@', 'some_mail@somewhere.net');
```

Answer (score 2):

`$email = $linha3['user_email'];`

`$email= substr($email, 0, 3).'****'.substr($email, strpos($email, "@"));`

Comment: Thanks! It's worked great! :)